# Why this can not be passed as default parameter in member function?

Tags: c++

I was trying to pass the current value of length as the default parameter as a function argument . 
but compiler is showing error that

> " 'this' may not be used in this context"

can any one tell me what is the mistake I have committed. ?

```
class A
{

    private:
    int length;
    public:
    A();
    void display(int l=this->length)
    {
        cout<<"the length is "<<l<<endl;
    }

};


int main()
{

    A a;
    a.display();    
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You could just use `length` instead of `this->length`.

Comment: @chris: Does it work that way?

Comment: @chris , I have already tried that ....that will not work.

Comment: @K-ballo, Good point. You have to look beyond what you see. I get it.

Comment: @chris: Actually, I was just curious if it would work...

Comment: @K-ballo, Well, no. `length` not being static is the next problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your member function:

```
void display(int l=this->length)
```

is conceptually equivalent to this:

```
void display(A * this, int l=this->length); //translated by the compiler
```

which means, you're using one parameter in an expression which is the default argument for other parameter which is not allowed in C++, as §8.3.6/9 (C++03) says,

> Default arguments are evaluated each
>   time the function is called. *The order
>   of evaluation of function arguments is
>   unspecified*. **Consequently, parameters
>   of a function shall not be used in
>   default argument expressions**, even if
>   they are not evaluated.

Note that C++ doesn't allow this:

```
int f(int a, int b = a); //illegal : §8.3.6/9
```

---

The solution is to add one overload which takes no parameter as:

```
void display()
{
    display(length); //call the other one!
}
```

If you don't want to add one more function then *choose an impossible default value* for the parameter. For example, since it describes *length* which can never be negative, then you may choose `-1` as the default value, and you may implement your function as:

```
void display(int l = -1)
{
      if ( l <= -1 ) 
           l = length; //use it as default value!
      //start using l 
}
```

Comment: I support this answer for thoroughness. +1

Comment: @Nawaz ... So can u please tell me how can pass the member variable....what is the best way in this situation ?

Comment: Is there any other to do this apart from adding one more function?

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: Added an alternative solution.

Comment: @AbhishekGupta: Yup. The first solution is muct better, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You could user overloading and forwarding instead.

```
class A
{
    private:
    int length;
    public:
    A();

    void display()
    {
        display(this->length);
    }

    void display(int l)
    {
        cout<<"the length is "<<l<<endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

At compile time, there is no object, so there is no this.

Why would you pass in one of your object's properties as a default value into a member function if that member function can access the property itself?

Comment: This answer makes no sense to me.

Comment: Well, as far as I could understand the original poster's problem he wants to pass a value to an object's member function when that value is actually accessible for that function since it is a member function. That didn't make sense to me. But perhaps I did not understand the question correctly.