# C++ default a parameter to another parameter

Tags: c++, parameters

Can I use the first parameter as a default for the second parameter, like this?

```
int do_something(int a, int b = a + 1){
    /* ... */
}
```

My compiler doesn't seem to like it, so perhaps it's not allowed.

Comment: Similar topic for member functions:  [Why this can not be passed as default parameter in member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167062/why-this-can-not-be-passed-as-default-parameter-in-member-function)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question has already been answered (it is not allowed), but in case you didn't realize, the workaround is trivial with function overloading.

```
int do_something(int a, int b){
    /* ... */
}

int do_something(int a) {
    return do_something(a, a + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It is not allowed.

> The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. Consequently, parameters of a
>   function shall not be used in a default argument, even if they are not evaluated.

(from [dcl.fct.default]/9 in C++14)

Answer (score -5):

if I were U I would do this

```
int do_something(int a, int b){
    b = a + 1;
    /* ... */
}
```

But the b value is not gonna change after the function complete executing. 
Passing b by reference will work. (int &b)

Comment: What's the purpose of having `b` as a parameter if you're just going to ignore what was passed and overwrite it?

Comment: if the function is initialized like this:    
     int do_something(int a, int &b)  
you can return one value while change variable b value at the same time